# Broadcast receiver is not working all the time in android studio app

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I am working on an app and data being sent via intent to activity is not being picked up by the broadcast receiver all the time. Only sometimes and I have no idea why. The intent is in a service class that sends the intent as send broadcast(intent)

This is my code for the activity which contains the broadcast receiver.

If anyone could help me that would be great.

```
public class MainActivity5 extends AppCompatActivity {

   protected static final String TAG = "TAG";

   TextView dataText;
   BroadcastReceiver receiver;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

      Log.i(TAG, "In Activity5");

      receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.i("Receiver1", "Broadcast received: " + action);
            if(action.equals("com.example.Pillwoah.sendbroadcast")){
                String data = intent.getExtras().getString("inputExtra");
            }
        }
      };

      Log.i(TAG, "configure Receiver");
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
      filter.addAction("com.example.Pillwoah.sendbroadcast");
      registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
   }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy(){
      super.onDestroy();
      unregisterReceiver(receiver);
      Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast receiver destroyed");
   }
}
```

Comment: Receiver should be registered between start-stop not create-destroy. If I remember correctly you should be getting errors in logcat about leaked receiver.

Comment: So I made a onReusme() and registered the receiver there and an onPause() to unregister the receiver and am getting the same thing as with the previous code. The broadcast receiver is not being registered. Should I try something different then the resume-pause?

Comment: So it works! I just have to be on that screen for that activity. I actually need the data to be transmitted constantly even when I am not on that activity's screen. Is there a way that can be done?

Comment: I switched to onStart() and onStop() and commented out onStop() and the data is being sent continously